# How to bind a certain DRL file to a certain KieSession in Drools 6.2.0

Tags: drools

I'm using Drools 6.2.0, and in my Maven project I have a few DRL files, each one with some different rules.
The main idea, is to have a few workers in the project, each one with a KieSession that will receive the objects that will be evaluated by the rules in the files.
I would like to bind a certain DRL file to a certain KieSession. I've seen that I can use the 'agenda-group' property, but I'm not sure how it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can compile any DRL file to a KnowledgePackage and create a KnowledgeBase from it, which is the origin for a KnowledgeSession. You may even serialize the KnowledgePackage or KnowledgeBase for faster startup.

All of this can be done using the API, so there's no need for messing around with agenda groups.

**EDIT** This is code working with 6.2.0, using an unblemished API.

```
private KieSession kieSession;

public void build(String dir, String drl) throws Exception {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    FileInputStream fis = 
       new FileInputStream( dir + "/" + drl );

    kfs.write( "src/main/resources/" + drl,
                kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ) );

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();

    Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
    if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
        System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
        throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
    }

    KieContainer kieContainer =
        kieServices.newKieContainer( kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );

    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
    kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
}
```

Comment: But isn't that deprecated in the 6.2.0 version?

Comment: You may have to use KieFilesystem and/or KieContainer, but this is in the stabel 6.2.0 API and does not show up with deprecated. - Anyway, agenda groups is not the way to go if you want to have different rule sets in different sessions.

Comment: I've spent a little more time in the Drools documentation, and have found something that might help me, in the [section 4.2.2](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch04.html#KIEBuildingSection). In here I've learned that it's possible to "bind" a certain package (with some DRL files in it) to a certain KieBase.
I'm leaving it here, and latter will provide an proper answer.

Comment: Updated my A with a code snippet that does it. It's basically the same as with 5.x, although names have changed a bit, and KnowledgePackages aren't handled explicitly any more.